# Suppose $Y, X, Z, W$ are random variables. What are sufficient conditions for which $E[Y\mid X=x, Z=z, W=w] = E[Y\mid X=x, Z=z]$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $Y, X, Z, W$ are random variables. I am wondering which sufficient conditions might exist for it to hold that,

$$
E[Y\mid X=x, Z=z, W=w] = E[Y\mid X=x, Z=z]
$$

Would it be sufficient if,

$$
W\perp Z \mid X
$$
?

In other words, $W$ being independent of $Z$ conditional on $X$?

Comment: I am just curious. Is the notation $Z | X$ used in a textbook of yours (outside of expressions like $P(Z \leq z|X)$ and $E(Z|X)$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bayes' Theorem:

$$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$$

we get:

$$\Pr(Y|X,Y,W)=\frac{\Pr(Y\cap W|X,Z)}{\Pr(W|X,Z)}$$

For this to be equal to $\Pr(Y|X,Z)$, $Y$ and $W$ should be independent.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by $W$ independent of $Z\mid X$ ? ($Z\mid X$ is not a random variable). To answer to your question, a sufficient condition is $Y$ and $W$ being independent.

Comment: Sorry, I mean $(W\perp Z) \mid X$, meaning conditional on $X$, $X$ is independent of $Z$.

Comment: What you wrote has no sense to me ! @user321627

Comment: I had a typo. I mean that conditional on $X$, $W$ is independent of $Z$.